# 16.5 Font Size in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, fonts, about-config

I'm using Bitstream Vera Sans as the sans-serif font in Firefox 11.0 beta for Windows 7 x64. There is a drastic jump in size from 16(pt?) to 17(pt?), to the point where 16 is barely legible, and 17 takes up too much space. I tried changing the value to 16.5 in about:config, but it told me that 16.5 isn't an integer (which it isn't). I fell in love with this font, so is there any option beyond dropping Vera?

This is Size 16:
[image: Size 16]

This is Size 17:
[image: Size 17]

Open the images in a new tab for full size. As you may be able to ascertain from the screenshot, I'm a fairly serious Wikipedia editor, and it helps to be able to read a lot of text at once, but I still need legibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [NoSquint](https://urandom.ca/nosquint) Firefox extension which allows one to control text zoom independently from overall zoom and then set the zoom incremental amount to something like 10% of normal (after setting your default sans-serif font size to 16 pts). This works for me in 32-bit Firefox 10.0.2.

Comment: It's a great add-on. Completely solved my issue.

Comment: @Yutsi: Glad to hear it solved your problem -- I wasn't sure about whether it'd work with a 64-bit build. NoSquint is a great add-on for Firefox -- I've been using it for a very long time. It effectively lets one customize the font size displayed on a site-by-site basis which it'll then remember between sessions.